# AS3 play flv clip faster and slower

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

Consider there is small few seconds clip of a man noding his head. I want to make his head nod faster and slower based on any key pressed event.fater key presses, faster head nods.

How can i achieve that in FLash/AS3 ?

1. Can this be done by loading external flv ? and make such controls ? If yes how ?
2. Should i import flv into movieClip/frames ? and then somehow run is faster and slower?

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It's Actionscript 2, but same method actually might work with AS3 too:
http://younsi.blogspot.it/2009/03/how-to-play-video-in-flash-in-slow.html